# Why does appending to innerHTML in a bookmarklet overwrite the entire page?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I have this little bookmarklet:

```
javascript:document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].innerHTML+="Chuck Norris";
```

Now it's obviously *supposed* to take the very first `div` on the page, and add Chuck Norris into it.

Instead, when pasted on the address bar, Chuck Norris overwrites the page.

Why is this so?

*Note: this doesn't occur on Safari...*

Comment: It doesn't do what you say on Chrome/Win, when entered into the JS console. (Entering into the address bar doesn't work because Omnibox.)

Comment: I'm not sure why this is downvoted. It is replacing the screen for me on Chrome.

Comment: Thank you, @millimoose... Wasn't aware that the Omnibox would do this... and why?

Comment: Why is this getting so many downvotes ?

Comment: @user2049022 My point was more that you need to specify how you're testing this better, since it's somewhat dependent on the exact process.

Comment: Fix the title up to mention it's a bookmarklet issue rather than put "Chuck Norris" in there.

Comment: Yeah, your title is pretty terrible. I guess people assume it's a joke post. Retitle it something like "why does appending to innerHTML in a bookmarklet refresh the page?"

Comment: Also, just returning a string from a bookmarklet does the same. (E.g. try with `javascript:"abc"`.) So I'd say the answer is "because that's what bookmarklets / `javascript:` URLs are supposed to do."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not cancelling the action. add void 0; to then end.

```
javascript:document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].innerHTML+="Chuck Norris";void 0;
```

Comment: Apparently there's a whole bunch of recommendations for bookmarklets to follow: http://subsimple.com/bookmarklets/rules.asp

Comment: why is void () necessary ?

Comment: thank you for your answer! :) and what is the difference from void and return false ?

Comment: [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void) ... It is just the way you need to use `javascript:` uri ... you last executed statement must resolve to undefined in a bookmarklet ... otherwise, that last value is converted to string and that is attempted to parse as an HTML page of its own.

Comment: `void(0);` is just the shortest way to get `undefined`. `undefined` = **9** characters ... **`void(0)` = 7 characters** ... `void 0` => `void%200` = **8** characters (%20 is space in bookmarklets)

Comment: _“You are not cancelling the action.”_ — Huh? The reason why this happens is that the script’s completion record has a value other than `undefined`; this completion record comes from evaluating that last expression statement. Adding `undefined;` or, equivalently, `void 0;` introduces another expression statement whose completion record _will_ have the value `undefined`.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what the exact problem is, but I got it working by making a textNode and appending it:

```
javascript:var d=document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];var n=document.createTextNode("Chuck Norris");d.appendChild(n);
```